# Cannot route to custom action in Yii2 controller

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am building a RESTful API with Yii2 (advanced) and endpoints are working as expected apart from a custom one I need.

My `urlManager`looks like:

```
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => 
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'api/v1/step', 'pluralize' => false],
    ],
```

If I add a custom action into the StepController like so it will work just fine - Calling with `http://example.com/api/v1/step/test`

```
public function actionTest()
```

However if I want to pass an ID in through the path I will receive a 404 error - `http://example.com/api/v1/step/test/1`

```
public function actionTest($id)
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Edit: Adding notes that may help others.

My example above was simplified but what I wanted my URL to look like was like `http://example.com/api/v1/step/test-by-foobar/1` with the called method to be `public function actionTestByFoobar($id)`. However to get this to work you have to set the urlManager rule like the following which I didn't find obvious:

```
'api/v1/step/test-by-foobar/1' => 'api/v1/step/test-by-foobar',
```

Notice that the value is hyphenated, not in camel-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your code you can pass an id like this :

```
http://example.com/api/v1/step/test?id=1
```

But if you want to do it like this:

```
http://example.com/api/v1/step/test/1
```

You should rewrite the url like below:

```
'urlManager' => [
     'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
     'showScriptName' => false,
     'rules' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
             'controller' => 'api/v1/step', 
             'pluralize' => false
            ],

            /* You are missing this line below */
            'api/v1/step/test/<id:\d+>' => 'api/v1/step/test'
     ]
],
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that but obviously incorrectly. It's working now.